# How are field variables initialized in Java?

Tags: java

I tried to run this program but this gives a runtime error(StackOverflowError). If in class Static I make reference object ob, static, then no error occurs. Can anyone please explain me why is this happening and please explain me how are field variables(whether static or non static and whether reference or non reference variables) initialized?

```
public class Static {

    public Static ob = new Static();
    private int a;

    public void win(Static obj) {
        //System.out.printf("ob.a = %d\n", ob.a);
        obj.a = 15;
        System.out.printf("ob.a = %d", ob.a);
    }
}

public class StaticTest {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Static obj=new Static();
        //Static obj1=new Static();

        // obj.win(obj1.ob);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. I have realized my mistake.

Comment: class **Static**, change this name, it is not telling the purpose of the class and is infact very misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code creates an instance of Static class.
When the instance is create their attributes are initialized. What your code does is to initialize the 'ob' attribute with pointing to a new Static instance.
Then the new instance of Static class is created, and ... you have an "infinite initialization loop".

If you attach 'static' keyworkd to an attribute you are creating a "class attribute", that is, an attributed shared among all instances of that class.
This means when you execute code and the first instance of Static is goind to be created JAva initialize the ob attribute. Subsequent instances of Static doesn't initialize it because it is shared among all.

See this sample: http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/staticvariable.shtml

Answer (score 5):

Each time you instantiate an object of `Static` class (very confusing name BTW) you create an object of `Static` and instantiate it, which create another object of `Static` and instantiate it and so on... (so you get a StackOverflow error):

```
public Static ob = new Static();
```

Comment: I second the comment "Static...very confusing name BTW".

Answer (score 1):

`static` fields are initialized once for all instances of the class. This is why changing the type to `static` stops it from infinite recursion.

When the field is not `static` you create an infinite recursion which leads to a stack overflow; when you instantiate the object, it instantiates another, which instantiates another, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Static is **at the class level** and hence it is initialized when the **class is loaded** in the memory for the first time. Also static blocks are init in order of there declaration.

As against, the class variables (non static) are per object and are **init when the object of that class is created**, not in any specific order, I believe.

In your case, if you don't make `ob` static, it will try to init the Static class object and when try to inti the ob, it again go and create another Static (as it calls new Static()) and this goes on for ever until you run out of stack (StackoverFlow).

if you make `ob` static, this is init only once (when Static class is loaded in memory) and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an instance level of a field, you are causing never-ending recursion, which ultimately ends up to StackOverFlow memory error.

If on the other hand you define your field as *static* you are avoiding the recursion, since the static field variables belong to the Class, not to the object instance. Classes in the JVM are only created once as opposed to Object instances, which can be numerous.